# Does JSoup achieve this?

Tags: java, jsoup, web-crawler

I want to collect domain names (crawling). I have wrote a simple Java application that reads HTML page and save the code in text file. Now, I want to parse this text in order to collect all domain names without douplicates. But I need the domain names without "http://www.", just domainname.topleveldmian or the possibilities of dmianname.subdomain.topleveldomain or whatever number of subdomains (then, the collected links need to be extracted the same way and collect the links inside them till I reach certain number of links, say 100).

I have asked about this in previous posts https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11113568/simple-efficient-java-web-crawler-to-extract-hostnames , and searched. JSoup seems good solution but I have not worked with JSoup before, so before going deeply on it. I just want to ask: Does it achieve what I want to do ?? Any other suggestions for achieving my simple crawling in a simple way are welcome.

Answer (score -1):

> jsoup is a Java library for working with real-world HTML. It provides
>   a very convenient API for extracting and manipulating data, using the
>   best of DOM, CSS, and jquery-like methods

So **yes**, you can connect to a website extract its html and parse it with jsoup.

The logic of extracting the *top level domain* is "your part" you will need to write the code logic yourself.

---

Take a look at the docs for more options...

[Use selector-syntax to find elements](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)

[Use DOM methods to navigate a document](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation)